# In python using matplotlib how to display multiline strings in ax.fmt_xdata

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib version 1.2.0 and python 2.7 on linux.

```
plot(numpy.arange(10))
ax = gca()
ax.fmt_xdata = lambda x: "line1 %d\nline2 %f"%(int(x),x)
```

On linux using the Qt4Agg backend it does not put line1 and line 2 on separate lines.  Can this be done with the Qt4Agg backend? (For reference on windows using TkAgg backend it works)